# How to determine the classes that will added or removed from an HTML tag when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm currently exploring a webpage where clicking a button triggers the addition or removal of classes from an HTML tag. The question is, before clicking the button, is there a way to identify the classes that will be added?

I attempted to retrieve the content of the onclick attribute of a button element using the getAttribute() method in JavaScript, but it returns null.

Comment: Your browser's dev-tools probably has a "Break on... > Attribute modifications" of some sort in its DOM tree's inspector. (Right click on the button's element DOM representation to see that menu). Otherwise you could use a MutationObserver but you'd be late, the attribute would already be changed at that point.